# Select or find everything that a driver is driving?

Tags: drivers

How can I find out all properties that a driver is driving without manually checking every object in the graph editor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A single driver only calculates the value for one property. I think what you want are properties a driver depends on, that is properties a driver uses in its calculation.

You can use the outliner to find objects that have drivers by searching for "driver" -

[image: outiner driver search]

I don't think blender includes a way to show driver dependancies but we can make a script to list them. Drivers and the variables we define to use in them are all stored in the animation data.

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object

if obj.animation_data and len(obj.animation_data.drivers):
    for d in obj.animation_data.drivers:
        if len(d.driver.variables):
            for v in d.driver.variables:
                if v.type == 'SINGLE_PROP' or v.type == 'TRANSFORMS':
                    print('{}.{}[{}] uses {} from {}'.format(
                            obj.name, d.data_path, d.array_index,
                            v.targets[0].data_path, v.targets[0].id.name))
                elif v.type == 'LOC_DIFF':
                    print('{}.{}[{}] uses distance between {} and {}'.format(
                            obj.name, d.data_path, d.array_index,
                            v.targets[0].id.name, v.targets[1].id.name))
                elif v.type == 'ROTATION_DIFF':
                    print('{}.{}[{}] uses rotational difference between {} and {}'.format(
                            obj.name, d.data_path, d.array_index,
                            v.targets[0].id.name, v.targets[1].id.name))
```

That will give you something like -

```
Suzanne.location[0] uses location.x from Cube
# or
Armature.pose.bones["Bone"].location[0] uses distance between Cube and Lamp
```

Note that this does not cover all driver data, just what is in the main animation data, which includes the main object properties as well as modifiers and armature bones. Drivers for shapekeys can be found in `obj.data.shape_keys.animation_data.drivers`, materials, textures and nodetrees can also have their own `animation_data`.

Comment: This is a bad news.  Two years later, do you know any better solution?