# Blender 2.9 scripting, how to get the name of the driven property

Tags: python, scripting, drivers

I'm trying to get the name of the property that's been affected by a driver for a certain object, what I did so far:

```
for d in bpy.context.object.animation_data.drivers:
    print(d.driver.id_data.name)
```

However, that's returning the name of the object, not the driven property. 
**My question is**, let's say there's a drive controlling the Z Scale, how do I get that information "Z Scale" or a similar equivalent, in scripting?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111662/select-or-find-everything-that-a-driver-is-driving

Comment: Thank you @batFINGER very helpful, as always

Comment: Cheers. Initially closed as  a dupe, ... changed mind after looking at answer script which will do nought if there are no variables, which is often the case with `use_self` or when using `frame` or other vars known to namespace.  Closing is no big deal tho, more in re to linking alike questions.

Comment: Totally agree, I believe answers to both questions are helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `f_curve.data_path`and `f_curve.array_index` to get the property index in case of vectorized properties (like location, scale, etc.)

```
import bpy

if bpy.context.active_object and bpy.context.active_object.animation_data:
    for d in bpy.context.active_object.animation_data.drivers:
        print(bpy.context.active_object)
        print(f"Driven property : {d.data_path}")
        print(f"Property index : {d.array_index}")
```

Example :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great answer, thank you